# Flask renaming uploaded file

Tags: python, flask

in my app i am uploading images to a folder but i cannot figure out how to rename them from the form to something

this is my .py

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("upload.html")

@app.route("/upload", methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images/')
    print(target)

    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    for file in request.files.getlist("file"):
        print(file)
        filename = file.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print(destination)
        file.save(destination)

    return render_template("complete.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4555, debug=True)
```

this is my .html
obviously the input type="text" isn't working for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload here</h1>
<form id="upload-form" action="{{url_for('upload')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" multiple></br>
    New name for image<input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="send">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in request.files.getlist("file"):
    print(file)
    filename = file.filename
    destination = "/".join([target, filename])
    print(destination)
    file.save(destination)
```

Here you set the destination for the file which includes the new filename. You set filename to file.filename - essentially you are saying to keep the filename.

To rename the file you can overwrite the filename like so:
    `filename = "myfile.jpg"`

This could be dynamic, eg:

```
# keep extension for later
extension = filename.split()[-1]
current_dt = datetime.datetime(
new_filename = "upload-{}.{}".format(
    time.time(), extension
)
```

This would save the file as something like: `1574685161.690482.jpg`